# wp_dropdown_pages with tax_query clause

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, pages, taxonomy

I'm display a dropdown list of custom post types in wordpress. This first block of code uses WP_Query

```
$houseQuery = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'house',
        'order'     => 'ASC',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby'   => 'title',
        'nopaging' => true,
        'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'teamtype',
            'field'     => 'slug',
            'terms'     => 'sectorteam', // exclude house posts in the sectorteam custom teamtype taxonomy
            'operator'  => 'NOT IN')
        ))
);
if( $houseQuery ->have_posts() ) :
    while ($houseQuery ->have_posts()) : $houseQuery->the_post();
        if(get_the_ID()==$c)
            $name=$post->post_title;
        echo '{ value:'.get_the_ID().', label: "'.get_the_title(get_the_ID()).'"},';
    endwhile;
endif;
```

This is the second cut of the code which uses 'wp_dropdown_page()' method and is a bit more concise

```
$args = array (
    'id' => 'house',
    'name' => 'house',
    'echo' => 1,
    'post_type' => 'house'
);
wp_dropdown_pages($args);
```

I need to exclude the posts defined by the 'tax_query' in the first example but am ensure how this can be done with the arguments that 'wp_dropdown_pages' uses.

I would like to only invoke one Query as part of the solution.

Comment: You appear to be confusing `$houseQuery` and `$companyList` in your first code.

Comment: i corrected the sudo code. i failed to make clear that i only want to execute one query as part of the solution, since i realise i could build the list of excludes in a seperate query and then pass this to the wp_dropdown_pages() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amusingly, the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_pages#Other_Parameters) for wp_dropdown_pages includes this:

> It is possible, but not confirmed, some of the paramters for the
>   function get_pages could be used for wp_dropdown_pages.

This must be at least partly true as I assume your use of `post_type` as an argument is successful. That being the case, give `exclude` a shot too.

In your `companyList` loop, build an array of post IDs to exclude:

```
$name=$post->post_title;
echo '{ value:'.get_the_ID().', label: "'.get_the_title(get_the_ID()).'"},';
$exclusions[] = get_the_ID();
```

Then just throw that argument into your `wp_dropdown_pages`:

```
$args = array (
    'id' => 'house',
    'name' => 'house',
    'echo' => 1,
    'post_type' => 'house',
    'exclude' => $exclusions
);
```

Comment: I made no mention of using tax_query - did you read my answer?

Comment: I did try the exclude but the documentation says this applies to a category and not a taxonomy

Comment: Am I missing something in your question? Do you not want to exclude the posts (found in your first sample) from `wp_dropdown_pages` (in your second sample)?

Comment: Yes - I want to exclude the posts found by the first sample when using the wp_dropdown_pages sample.

Comment: Then my answer should work. Please try it as I described.

Comment: Ah I understand now. Your question was confusing as the first 'cut' does not output a dropdown in any way. The answer is much simpler then - use the first version. You cannot make those exclusions using `wp_dropdown_pages` alone.